# Prove that the map $\phi: V \rightarrow V^*$ is injective

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex inner product space and $\mathcal{B}=\lbrace v_1,\ldots v_n \rbrace$ an orthogonal basis for $V$. Let $\mathcal{B}^*= \lbrace f_1,\ldots f_n \rbrace$ be the dual basis where $f_i(x)=\frac{\langle x, v_i \rangle}{\|v_i\|^2}$ and $\|v_i\|^2=\langle v_i, v_i \rangle$. 
>   Show that the map  $\phi: V \rightarrow V^*$ by $v \mapsto \langle \text{ }, v \rangle$ is injective.

I am a little unsure what the notation "$\langle \text{ }, v \rangle$" actually means. I guess since it lives in $V^*$ then it could be the linear functional $f_v$ defined by $f_v(x)=\frac{\langle x, v \rangle}{\|v\|^2}$. If this is true, how do I show that the map is injective? Assume that $f_v=f_w$, so $f_v(x)=f_w(x)$ for all $x \in V$, how do I conclude that $v=w$?

Comment: $<, > : V \times V \to \mathbb{F}$ is the inner product on $V$ (since it is an inner product space). So, the function $<, v> : V \to \mathbb{F}$ where one of the arguments is already supplied is a linear functional. That's how you get a map $V \to V^* : v \to <, v>$.

Comment: hint: the kernel must only be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost: It's the map the takes $v$ to the function

$$x \mapsto \langle x, v\rangle$$
This function is an element of $V^*$ since it takes vectors $x \in V$ and spits out complex numbers.

Perhaps it's more clear if you write it as

$$v \mapsto \big(x \mapsto \langle x, v\rangle\big)$$

---

To show this is injective, it is equivalent to showing that if $v$ and $w$ are vectors for which
$$\langle x, v\rangle = \langle x, w\rangle$$

for all $x \in V$, then $v = w$. Notice that this can be rewritten as

$$\langle x, v - w\rangle = 0\quad\quad \forall x \in V$$
Now a clever choice of $x$ lets you compute $v - w$.

Comment: choose $x=v-w$, right?

Comment: Yep. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

$\langle \cdot, v \rangle$ is the function $x \mapsto \langle x, v \rangle$. First, note the map is linear. How do you determine if a linear map is injective, and what properties of the inner product space can you use to determine the map is injective?