# Prove that the map $\phi: V \rightarrow V^*$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex inner product space and $\mathcal{B}=\lbrace v_1,\ldots v_n \rbrace$ an orthogonal basis for $V$. Let $\mathcal{B}^*= \lbrace f_1,\ldots f_n \rbrace$ be the dual basis where $f_i(x)=\frac{\langle x, v_i \rangle}{\|v_i\|^2}$ and $\|v_i\|^2=\langle v_i, v_i \rangle$. 
>   Show that the map  $\phi: V \rightarrow V^*$ by $v \mapsto \langle \text{ }, v \rangle$ is surjective. i.e., For every $g \in V^*$, we can find $v \in V$ such that $g=\phi(v)$.

So here is what I did so far: let $g=\sum{a_if_i}$. I want to find $v \in V$ so that $\langle x,v \rangle=g(x)$ for all $x \in V$. Write $x=\sum{b_jv_j}$. By definition we can compute that $g(x)=\sum{a_ib_i}$. Let $v=c_jv_j$. So $\langle x,v \rangle = \langle \sum{b_iv_i},\sum{c_jv_j} \rangle= \sum{\overline{c_i}b_i \langle v_i,v_i \rangle}= \sum{a_ib_i}=g(x)$ for all $x \in V$. Am I on the right track? How do I solve $v$? Moreover, if we are over the real field instead of complex field, does the surjectivity still hold?

I asked a similar question yesterday about the injectivity of the map $\phi$. [Prove that the map $\phi: V \rightarrow V^*$ is injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624471/prove-that-the-map-phi-v-rightarrow-v-is-injective).  Here is the second part of that problem.

Comment: I saw this question yesterday and you might search for a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624471) you already know that $\phi$ is injective. Because $V$ is finite-dimensional and you mention the dual basis I assume you know that $\dim V = \dim V^*$.

We have the following well-known result:

> ***Theorem:*** Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional $K$-vector spaces with $\dim V = \dim W$ and $f \colon V \to W$ be $K$-linear. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is injective.
> 2. $f$ is surjective.
> 3. $f$ is bijective.
>
> ***Proof:*** We have
>   $$
>  \dim \operatorname{im} f = \dim V - \dim \ker f.
> $$
>   That $f$ is injective is equivalent to $\ker f = 0$ and thus $\dim \operatorname{im} f = \dim V = \dim W$, which is equivalent to $\operatorname{im} f = W$, i.e. $f$ being surjective. As $f$ is injective if and only if it is surjective the statement follows.

Therefore we can follows from the injectivity of $\phi$ that it is also surjective.

Comment: I think the problem asks to give an explicit expression for $v$. If not this could be easily solved by your method.

Comment: The way I see it the question justs asks to _show that the map $\phi \colon V \to V^*$ by $v \mapsto \langle \;, v \rangle$ is surjective_, while recalling what it means for $\phi$ to be surjective In this case I would regard it as a matter of taste in which way we show the statement, as both are relatively simple.

Answer (score 1):

If we can show the statement for each $f_i$, we done, cause if $f\in V^*$, then $f=a_1f_1+...+a_nf_n$ and since we have $f_i=\langle \cdot,u_i\rangle$ (that is, statement is true for each $f_i$), then $f=a_1\langle\cdot,u_1\rangle+...+a_n\langle\cdot,u_n\rangle=\langle\cdot,a_1u_1+....+a_nu_n\rangle$. Thus, statement is true for all $f\in V^*$.

Let us proof statement for each $f_i$. Fix $i$. Then $f_i$ is of the form $\langle \cdot,v\rangle$ iff $\langle x,v\rangle=f_i(x)=\frac{\langle x,v_i\rangle}{\|v_i\|^2}$ for all $x\in V$. Taking $v=\frac{v_i}{\|v_i\|^2}$ we done.